# How to make PhpStorm understand Ds\Map key type?

Tags: php, data-structures, phpstorm, type-hinting

I want to have type checking on a `Ds\Map` variable. In order to do this I've declared a dummy interface and declared types there:

```php
/**
 * @method OtherType offsetGet(MyType $offset)
 * @method void offsetSet(MyType $offset, OtherType $value)
 */
interface MyMap extends ArrayAccess, Iterator
{
}
```

But when I use it:

```php
/** @var Map|MyMap $map */
$map = new Ds\Map();
$map[$offset] = $value;
```

- PhpStorm doesn't recognize it and shows a warning: `Illegal array key type MyType`. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Use sth like this in the first of your code to say to the phpstorm where is your interface:

```
use nampespace\MyMap;
```

Comment: i actually do, just didn't mention it to simplify the example. i've just also noticed that laravel container type hinting also broke :( . - maybe it's a bug of phpstorm...